# Doing regex style compare while looping through a XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, regex

I have a XML file that i am using to loop through an on matching of a child node getting the value of a an attribute.The thing is matching these values with a * character or ? character like some regex style..can someone tell me how to do this .So if a request comes like g.portal.com it should match the second node .I am using .net 2.0

Below is my XML file

```
<Test>
   <Test Text="portal.com" Sample="1" />
   <Test Text="*.portal.com" Sample="201309" />
   <Test Text="portal-0?.com" Sample="201309" />       
</Test>



XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
  xDoc.Load(PathToXMLFile);
 foreach (XmlNode node in xDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
                         {

                             if (node.Attributes["Sample"].InnerText == value)
                             {

                             }

                         }
```

Comment: Why don't you use handy LINQ to XML instead? Regex and XML don't mix too well for theoratical reasons.

Comment: Well I gotta use .Net 2.0 so wanted to keep it to the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is first convert each `Text` attribute into a valid `Regex` pattern and then use it to match your input. Something like this:

```
string input = "g.portal.com";
XmlNode foundNode = null;
foreach (XmlNode node in xDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
    string value = node.Attributes["Text"].Value;
    string pattern = Regex.Escape(value)
        .Replace(@"\*", ".*")
        .Replace(@"\?", ".");
    if (Regex.IsMatch(input, "^" + pattern + "$"))
    {
        foundNode = node;
        break;  //remove if you want to continue searching
    }
}
```

After executing the above code, `foundNode` should contain the second node from the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

So you have an XML file that sets up patterns, right? You'll want to feed those patterns into `Regex`es and then stream a number of requests through them. Did I get that correct?

Assuming the XML file doesn't change it only needs to be processed into according `Regex`es. For example `*.portal.com` would translate to

```
new Regex("\\w+\\.portal\\.com");
```

You'll just have to escape the dots, replace `*` with `\\w+` and `?` with `\\w` if i guessed the semantics of you match patterns correctly.

Look up the correct replacements at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx